# Pass set from child to parent then to include twig

Tags: twig

Hi I need to pass color variable from a child file to include that is in parent file.
I try to make a simple example:

```
//File: _navbar.html.twig
<header class="navbar navbar-{{ color }}">...</header>

//File: base.html.twig
<body>
{{ include('_navbar.html.twig', {color: color}) }}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{{ include('_footer.html.twig') }}
</body>

//File: theme.html.twig
I want to pass color from here
```

I try to make a block in base.html.twig file like this:

```
{% block navbar_style %}{% set color="light" %}{% endblock %}
```

and rewrite the block in theme.html.twig but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i answer my self.

```
//File: _navbar.html.twig
<header class="navbar navbar-{{ color }}">...</header>

//File: base.html.twig
<body>
{{ include('_navbar.html.twig', {color: color ?? 'light'}) }}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{{ include('_footer.html.twig') }}
</body>

//File: theme.html.twig
{% set color="dark" %}
```

i set color directly in theme.html.twig and not in any block then I set a default value when I pass the variable to the included file.

Comment: Thanks for remember the lectors!